# get all dlls of specific namespace from directory

Tags: c#, dll, directory, .net-assembly

Is there any way to use this:
Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin")
but filter by the namespace?
what I want is all dlls of directory path which has specific namespace

Answer (score 0):

Load the assembly using:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("path/to/assembly");
```

Fetch all types and check the namespaces used:

```
foreach(var t in assembly.GetTypes()) { 
    var ns = t.Namespace;
    // Check namespace
}
```